# Fancybox add script to Ajax content

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display my content in Ajax mode. I want to add [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to the scrollbar of a div in the displayed content but it is not showing. On the page of the content the mCustomScrollbar is working fine, but not in the fancyBox Ajax window.

I presume I have to call the second script with *beforeLoad* or *beforeShow* callbacks but neither is working.

```
    beforeShow: function(){
        $(".textItem").mCustomScrollbar();
    }
```

Is this at all possible?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: did u tried adding function in afterShow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 afterShow: function(){
    $(".textItem").mCustomScrollbar();
}
```